# nodeJS child_process.spawn does not work when one of the args has a space in it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use the `child_process.spawn` function. The syntax is

```
child_process.spawn(command, args=[], [options])
```

Whenever I include a space in any of the elements of the args array, the command simply emits the argument. Here is some code I used to test it

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn

console.log("This works");
var watcher = spawn("ls", ["-l"]);
watcher.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    process.stdout.write(data.toString());
});

console.log("This does not work");
watcher = spawn("ls", ["-l", "/path with space in it"]);
watcher.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    process.stdout.write(data.toString());
});
```

Is this a bug in node? Do I need to escape the space?

Edit: The above code is just an example. Here is the real code.
Maybe is has to do with the pipes?

```
watcher = spawn("supervisor", ["--extensions\ 'coffee|js|css|coffeekup'", "src/app.coffee"]);
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me using Node 0.6.17 on Linux in the REPL. Created a directory with the same name at root level, and used your code.

Comment: Also worked from a file. Could you provide more information like Node version and OS?

Comment: What version of node are you running?

Comment: I just rebuilt from source to version 0.6.19 and I am running linux.

Comment: I'm confused. Did you try the original code you posted, or not?

Comment: I wrote it as a test case, neither of them work.

Comment: Very strange. I updated to 0.6.19, built from source, and I have no problem with your first example.

Comment: So weird, ill update if I find an answer.

Comment: Try this: `watcher = spawn("supervisor", ["--extensions", "coffee|js|css|coffeekup", "src/app.coffee"]);`.

Comment: Thanks that worked great, if you add it to a answer I will mark it as correct

Comment: The question should be edited. `spawn("ls", ["-l", "/path with space in it"])` works as expected; `spawn("supervisor", ["--extensions 'coffee|js|css|coffeekup'", "src/app.coffee"])` wasn't working as OP expected.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Don't put spaces in `args`, just use another argument in the array

```
var watcher = spawn("supervisor", [
  "--extensions",
  "'coffee|js|css|coffeekup'",
  "src/app.coffee"
]);
```

A handy little shortcut I found if you want to get quick diagnostic output from your child processes is passing the `{stdio: "inherit"}` in `options`

```
var watcher = spawn("supervisor", [
  "--extensions",
  "'coffee|js|css|coffeekup'",
  "src/app.coffee"
], {stdio: "inherit"});
```

This way you can see whether everything is working properly right away.

Lastly, depending on where `supervisor` is installed, you might want to consider using the full path.

```
var watcher = spawn("/path/to/supervisor", ...);
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to use command substitution inside of a spawn call? Something like `docker rm $(docker ps -a)`

Comment: This is bash. You use "exec" for that: `child_process.exec('rm $(docker ps -a)', {shell: '/bin/bash'}, console.log)`.

Comment: Do you need the single quotes around file extensions?