# Does the NodeJS's child process args array sanitize arguments?

Tags: node.js, security, sanitization, child-process

Say you're building an app that runs a shell command based on unverified input.

Concatenating the arguments as a string is obviously a massive security risk, but is it the same case with the [`args`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) option?

The docs don't mention anything about this. I ran a quick test:

```
var child = require("child_process");

child.spawn("touch", ["./filename", "&& touch ./hacked"]);
```

`filename` is created, but `hacked` isn't. Does that mean I can plug anything in the `args` array and assume it's safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue you're seeing isn't that it's sanitizing your input for you, I think it's that you can't use spaces in your arguments.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941545/nodejs-child-process-spawn-does-not-work-when-one-of-the-args-has-a-space-in-it).

I couldn't find anything online that gave any indication that your child spawning arguments are sanitized.

Comment: True enough. Changing that argument list on the third line to `["./filename", "&&", "touch", "./hacked"]` gets `hacked` to appear. Have yourself an accepted answer.

Comment: Hmm, I may have jumped the gun on this - running with that updated argument list also creates the files `&&` and `touch` - so `hacked` appearing there is due to the initial `touch`...

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw, but you can still use spaces, you just have to escape them first.